# Redshift cluster and Subnet cluster group AZ mismatch

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have read that Redshift cluster is usually a single AZ deployment. But when creating Cluster subnet group, we can specify subnets from different AZs. How is that possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I got the answer - When creating cluster, we can defined AZ. if we dont define Az, any one from cluster subnet group will be used. Is this understanding correct ?

Comment: Correct, you can tell Redshift which subnets are allowed and Redshift will pick one of those.

Comment: add this as answer & will mark & close @MP24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you can tell Redshift which subnets are allowed and Redshift will pick one of those.

To quote from the [Redshift management guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-cluster-subnet-groups.html):

> When provisioning a cluster you provide the subnet group and Amazon Redshift creates the cluster on one of the subnets in the group.